# How to detect Windows 2012 Core edition (C++)

Tags: c++, windows-server

I need to detect the edition on Windows 2012 in my program.
On previous OS I used GetProductInfo's pdwReturnedProductType, but according to msdn:

> PRODUCT_*_SERVER_CORE values are not returned in Windows Server 2012. For example, the base server
> edition, Server Datacenter, is used to build the two different installation options: "full server"
> and   "core server". With Windows Server 2012, GetProductInfo will return PRODUCT_DATACENTER
> regardless of   the option used during product installation.

Is there any other possibility to detect core edition?

Comment: Why? The two "products" are now the same product, but with different components installed.

Comment: In my case, because Core edition using special version of .NET (http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=22833), which is a bit different. Some .NET Framework features do not work on Server Core.

Comment: Eh, isn't that 4.0 .Net Framework for Server 2008 entirely redundant on Server 2012 (which comes with 4.5 included) ?

Comment: It is still differs from Core edition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, I did not find any correct way to detect Windows Core Edition.
So, the solution was, for Win 2012, to detect dwm.exe process is running (Desktop Window Manager). It is always running, can't be killed by user and not exists on Windows Core editions.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is true for Windows Server 2012 - I can see DWM.EXE running on my core server with GUI-MGMT installed.

Answer (score 2):

```
HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Server\ServerLevels\
    ServerCore = 1
    Server-Gui-Mgmt = 1
    Server-Gui-Shell = 1
```

according to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh846315%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) using these registry values is one way. 
Another would be to parse the output of dism `/online /get-features /format:table` and see if the feature ServerCore-FullServer is enabled or disabled. If its disabled then you are in servercore gui-less mode.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a program/function that tests for a feature/library not present in the Core edition of .NET. For example:

```
using System;

public class CoreChecker
{
    public static void Main(string args[])
    {
        try
        {
            ImportNonCoreComponent();

            Console.WriteLine("NonCoreAssembly found... this is full server.");
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("NonCoreAssembly not found... this is core server.");
        }
    }

    public static void ImportNonCoreComponent()
    {
        using NonCoreAssembly;
    }
}
```

If this does not work, you will need to move the using to the class scope then create a class from NonCoreAssembly in ImportNonCoreComponent (I can't recall the exact semantics of how this works).

NOTE: The using statement needs to be isolated to the test function. When the JIT compiler processes it, it will throw an exception. That exception will not be processed by the test function, so the try...catch statement needs to be in the method that calls it.

You can use this technique to implement a custom action in an MSI to fail during install, or use it as part of your C# application to bring up a message saying "You need to use full server." (which will work if they install the app then downgrade to Core).

If the difference is behavioural, you can check that behaviour in your test function.

Make sure that the test function works in different scenarios and with different .NET versions.

Comment: That's very interesting trick, but it does not suits to me. I pointed about C++ in question header. I have the following scenario: cpp part is running, detects Core edition, than starts Managed.exe or Managed.NoGUI.exe